# Select columns thats greater than?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql, sequelpro

I have a table(mysql) and in my query I would like to get only the columns that are greater or equal to 4, but I have no clue how to do that.

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE * (all foo columns foo1-foo7) >= 4 AND date = '2015-09-03'
```

My table looks like:

```
id | foo1 | foo2 | foo3 | foo4 | foo5 | foo6 | foo 7 | date
-----------------------------------------------------
1  |   5  |  10  |  8   |  0   |   2  |  4   |  5    | 2015-09-03
2  |   7  |  18  |  0   |  1   |   0  |  5   |  7    | 2015-09-04
```

so my result should be:

```
id | foo1 | foo2 | foo3 | foo6 | foo 7 | date
-----------------------------------------------------
1  |   5  |  10  |  8   |  4   |  5    | 2015-09-03
```

Is this possible?

Comment: This isn't really how relational databases are supposed to be used. If you have more than one row, you'd have variable columns as some would and wouldn't be included per row based on the contents.

Comment: If the date is not unique and you will want to ask later for more than one ROW then you cannot do this in SQL. If you want only single row and the date is unique, then just get the resukt and edit it later...

Comment: the date is uniqe i have one row for every day like '2015-09-03' and so on, i can accomplish this later with jquery but i was wondering if i could filter this in my question so i dont need to if/else me throw all columns

Comment: A SELECT statement always returns the same set of columns, independent of the current table data. So you can not write a SELECT that for sometimes returns 7 columns, and sometimes 6, or 8 or any other number of columns.

Comment: Okej @jarlh thank you, then i just use jquery or php to filter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The more appropriate answer (for an RDBMS) is to use two tables with a foreign key relationship and constraint.

```
MASTER
ID                DATE
1                 2015-09-03

DETAIL
ID       MASTER_ID    MYNAME  MYVALUE
1        1            tom     5
2        1            bill    10
3        1            kev     8
4        1            bob     0
5        1            other   2
6        1            bleh    4
7        1            snarf   5
```

then

```
SELECT m.id, m.date, d.myvalue FROM master m 
INNER JOIN detail d ON m.id = d.master_id 
WHERE m.date = '2015-09-03' AND d.myvalue > 4
```

this gives you multiple rows, but then you can use your RDBMS's PIVOT function to turn this into something else if you wish.

e.g.

```
SELECT m.id, m.date, d.myvalue FROM master m 
INNER JOIN detail d ON m.id = d.master_id 
WHERE m.date = '2015-09-03' AND d.myvalue > 4
PIVOT myvalue FOR myname
```

(sql server syntax) you'd end up with

```
ID    date        tom    bill    kev    snarf
1     2015-09-03  5      10      8      5
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE id >= 4 AND foo1 >=4 AND foo2 >=4 AND date = '2015-09-03'
```

Fill the rest of the foos, Avoid using IS and comparison operators together.

Comment: so the output will have only columns which you run in this query?

Comment: @Jai As long as he have fixed structure then, Yes. safe way.

Comment: Nope, it always selects ALL columns (SELECT * tends to do this!) and only the rows where the ID is > 4 (for what reason???) and foo1 is >4. Which makes precious little sense!